# Postgres corrupted DB recovery

Tags: postgresql, recovery

Is there a way to recover data from partially damaged Postgres DB? My HDD was damaged in transport, I was able to recover most of the files but I cannot connect to the DB or use dump: I'm getting error:

```
psql: FATAL:  could not read block 0 in file "base/18819/11700": read only 0 of 8192 bytes.
```

This is one of the missing files though most of them are fine. Is there a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a special option: `zero_damaged_pages=on` that you can use on postgresql.conf, it is documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-developer.html#GUC-ZERO-DAMAGED-PAGES).

This option will allow for a pg_dump (or pg_dump_all) that do not stop on critical errors and get as much data back as possible, but you will loose the data that cannot be read.:

(exceprt from documentation, I added the strong.

> Detection of a damaged page header normally causes PostgreSQL to
>   report an error, aborting the current transaction. Setting
>   zero_damaged_pages to on causes the system to instead report a
>   warning, zero out the damaged page in memory, and continue processing.
>   **This behavior will destroy data**, namely **all the rows on the damaged
>   page**. However, it does allow you to get past the error and retrieve
>   rows from any undamaged pages that might be present in the table. It
>   is useful for recovering data if corruption has occurred due to a
>   hardware or software error. You should generally not set this on until
>   you have given up hope of recovering data from the damaged pages of a
>   table. Zeroed-out pages are not forced to disk so it is recommended to
>   recreate the table or the index before turning this parameter off
>   again. The default setting is off, and it can only be changed by a
>   superuser.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way in this case is to recover from a backup file if you have one of them ... To restore from a backup file you can use the [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html) utility .

Answer (score 0):

for people looking for an emergency working option check :

"
Bringing the standby out of recovery mode: Run

/path/to/pg_ctl promote -D /path/to/data/directory

"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015587/how-to-exit-out-of-database-recovery-mode-currently-locked-in-read-only-mode

I had this problem....

LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at log time  2023-07-15 01:42:17 -05
LOG:  entering standby mode
LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 2AE/10000098
LOG:  postgres invalid record length at 2AE/10000098:  wanted 24 got 0
LOG: database system is ready to accept read only connections

or in spanish

LOG:  el sistema de bases de datos fue apagado durante la recuperación en 2023-07-15 00:02:40 -05
LOG:  entrando al modo standby
LOG:  el estado de recuperación consistente fue alcanzado en 2AE/10000098
LOG:  largo de registro no válido en 2AE/10000098: se esperaba 24, se obtuvo 0
LOG:  el sistema de bases de datos está listo para aceptar conexiones de sólo lectura